# Differential forms defined by integration

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $\omega_1,\omega_2$ be two n-forms on a $n$-dimensional manifold $M$.

Now, imagine we have for every open $N \subset M$ that

$$\int_{N}\omega_1 = \int_N \omega_2.$$

Can anybody show me how to prove that both forms are equal?- I suspect that this is true as it sounds natural, although I don't know for sure.

Comment: You need to say what $M$ is before we can know what $N \subset M$ means.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: If $M$ is the manifold, this doesn't make any sense unless $p = n$. You can only integrate $p$-forms on $p$-folds. If you rephrase your question to: "If (integrals) are equal for every $N$ a compact smooth embedded $p$-dimensional submanifold, are the forms equal?" then the answer is yes. Think about the $p=n$ case first: what happens when you pick the $N$ to be very small balls around a chosen point?

Comment: intuitively this seems reasonable as we force equality on a basis of $p$-forms by looking at submanifolds which focus on each basis element of the $p$-forms in $n$-dimensional space. For three dimensional space, and looking at a two-form, you'd need $dx \wedge dy$, $dy \wedge dz$ and $dz \wedge dx$ which you could obtain equality by sorting through the right sort of submanifolds. There are technical issues to address which the other comments point you towards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a $n$-form $\omega :=\omega_1-\omega_2$ so that $$ \omega = f\nu $$ where $\nu$ is a volume form on $M$.

If $f(p)>0$ so $f|_{B_\epsilon (p)} > 0$ Then $$ 0=\int_{B_\epsilon (p)} \omega $$ Hence we conclude that $f=0$.